# Compiling issue with SFML library in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, sfml

I am making some project using SFML. I have downloaded library from their official site, using cmake I made VS10 project, compiled it and got all the libs and files I need. However, in my project I keep getting nonsense errors like

> class "sf::SoundBuffer" has no member "LoadFromFile"
>
> class "sf::Sound" has no member "SetBuffer"

even though I have checked in SoundBuffer header there is a function named LoadFromFile and in Sound there is a function called SetBuffer.

```
  SoundM::SoundM(void) 
  {
     buffer.LoadFromFile("ress/soundA.wav");
     collision.SetBuffer(buffer);
  }



   #ifndef SOUND_H
   #define SOUND_H

    enum Sounds {
PaddleCollision,
Losing
    };

     class SoundM {
     public:
SoundM(void);
void play(Sounds Sound);
    private:
sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
sf::Sound collision;
    };

    #endif
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Clean up code, please. And do not delete asked question this time.

Comment: Did you include the needed .h files?

Comment: Yes, I have. This is very strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using the SFML version 2.0 RC. There was a name convention change and now, all function names start with a lowercase letter (camel case).

So you should try that.

```
buffer.loadFromFile("ress/soundA.wav");
collision.setBuffer(buffer);
```

Instead of that.

```
buffer.LoadFromFile("ress/soundA.wav");
collision.SetBuffer(buffer);
```

I hope that helps you!